# Completing Git branch names “from the middle”

Tags: zsh

At work we name our Git branches in a verbose way, like “feature/PROJ-123-frobnicate-blobs”. In order to use the Zsh autocompletion with names like this, I end up typing the “feature/PROJ-” boilerplate over and over. I would love to be able to type

> git switch 123<kbd>Tab</kbd>

and have “123” replaced with that entire branch name.

More generally, instead of autocompletion assuming that what I’ve typed is the *beginning* of the branch name, it should assume that I’ve merely given it a substring.

How can I configure Zsh to complete Git branch names in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'l:|=*'
```

Or, if you already have a similar statement in there, add `l:|=*` to it.

Alternatively, try my [Zsh Autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete), which includes a fine-tuned completion config.

Comment: This didn’t work for me, unfortunately. (I had another `matcher-list` style to make matching case-insensitive, but I disabled that completely in order to test your suggestion.) Are there shell options that could be interfering with this working?

Comment: Aha—it looks like my `$fpath` was not set correctly and so Zsh didn’t know about the “good” Git completion script. (I believe this is the one that ships with Zsh and *not* the one that ships with Git.) Once I got that in place, this suggestion started working. I would be curious how I could restrict this kind of matching to only Git branch names for now, though—right now this `zstyle` applies everywhere and could change the completion behavior in other contexts in an unwanted way.

Comment: Like I said, try my plugin https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete or have a look at the included config: https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/blob/main/scripts/.autocomplete.config

Comment: Also, see my answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65842518/13832769

Comment: In any case, you should probably close your question, since the solution you needed has nothing to do with the question you asked. :)

Comment: Your solution *was* the one I needed; it’s just that I needed to do some tweaking to my configuration first.

Comment: Then please click the button to Accept my answer. :)